# Казачья Лопань

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Есть такая река и городок на границе Украины и России — Казачья Лопань. А что означает слово "лопань" и почему она "казачья"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лопань - родник (на болоте обычно) или колодец.
Ну а "Казачья" - это естественно. Жили там казаки - значит казачья. Лопаней вообще-то много, и такое "разделение" встречается у топонимов с одинаковыми названиями.